# developブランチにmainブランチを取り込む方法/順番

Tags: git

`develop`ブランチに`main`ブランチを取り込む方法はいくつかあると思うのですが、おすすめの方法を教えてください。

正解があるのであればそれを教えてほしいです。

自分が思いつくのはこんな感じです。パターン①がいいと思っています。

### パターン①(pushを先にする)

```
git checkout develop
~プログラミング~
git add .
git commit -m "commit"
git push
git merge main
~conflict修正~
git add .
git commit -m "commit"
git push
```

### パターン②(mergeを先にする)

```
git checkout develop
~プログラミング~
git add .
git commit -m "commit"
git merge main
~conflict修正~
git add .
git commit -m "commit"
git push
```

### パターン③(pullでmergeをする)

```
git checkout develop
~プログラミング~
git add .
git commit -m "commit"
git push
git pull main develop
~conflict修正~
git add .
git commit -m "commit"
git push
```

Comment: あなた自身はそれぞれどのような違いがあると捉えていて、なぜ一つ目がよいと考えるのかを説明したほうが回答もつきやすくなる気がします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gitの作業においてはいろんな方法がありますが、
重要なことは「どういったコミットができるか」が最も大事です。

つまりは正解かどうかは作業の「方法」ではなくて作業の「結果」が大事です。

その視点で考えると実は３つのやり方どれでもいいということになります。
なぜなら出来上がるコミットがすべて一緒だからです。以下になるでしょう。

（前のコミット）→　作業コミット(コメント commit) → マージコミット

１でも２でも３でもどっちでも出来上がるコミット内容は変わらないと思います。

じゃあ方法として何が良いかは、正解はないのでご自身で合わせて作業すればよいと思います。

それを踏まえて３つの作業のレビューをしてみると、
いかに作業しやすいか、いかに安全に作業できているか？というポイントになりそうです。

例えば
１の作業は途中でpushしているので仮にローカルが途中で失われてもリモートから復帰できる安全といえますが、すでにマージの作業が必要であると理解しているならばpushする前にマージ作業したほうが効率はよいでしょう。

ちなみにpullというコマンドは中身としては「fetch+merge」とほぼ一緒です。
マージするべき履歴の内容を理解しているのであればpullで履歴を確認せずに一気にマージしてもよいですし、きちんと履歴を確認して作業するのであれば「fetch+merge」で作業したほうがいいかなと思います。

どちらにせよご自身の作業状況や何を重要にするかによって、作業方法をいろいろ試してみるとよいと思います。